# error uploading app for iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I get an error when I try to submit app to app store ,the error ocurrs on the last step ( app is being uploaded )

Error : "`an error occurred while uploading to the app store`"

I doubled checked my certificated and profile and my app configuration on both XCode and iTunes connect.

I tried using the Application Loader but I'm getting the same error

I also tried changing the Java version from 1.7 to 1.6 as many answers suggesting but it didn't work

I'm on Xcode 4.6.2 , OSX 10.8.3 and on java version "1.6.0_45"

Note that when I choose Validate instead of Distribute after archiving the app I get no errors. the error only appears when I try to submit to the app store

**EDIT**
I restored the Java version to 1.7.0_21 since it seems that the problem is not caused by Java ,

the application loader shows the following two errors in the error log

*/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter: line 14: awk: command not found*

*/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter: line 18: ../share/iTMSTransporter.woa/iTMSTransporter: No such file or directory*

I reinstalled Xcode as a desperate attempt to solve this issue but with no luck

Comment: `cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`
`sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5`
`sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0`

this worked fine for me. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4451649?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many methods that were suggested in apple forums and on stackoverflow but non of them worked for me. so I decided to backup my OSx lion and re-install the system all over again.

I know that this might be too radical solution but I had to do it because nothing else worked.

Comment: YES, but I skipped the Java update listed in the software updates

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and was able to fix it by slightly adapting the file

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
```

change the path to the awk to absolute (and i also uncommented the echo of the script path, which probably isn't necessary). Here my changed file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# if the user has the run script in their PATH
# then we can get the path to the script from
# 'which'.  otherwise, we have to get the path
# from $0
if [ "$0" = "iTMSTransporter" ] ; then
  SCRIPT_PATH=`which iTMSTransporter`
else
  SCRIPT_PATH=$0
fi

# get the script's directory
SCRIPT_DIR=`echo $SCRIPT_PATH | /usr/bin/awk -F"/" '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-length($NF))}'`

# call the transporter relative to the script's directory
echo Calling: ${SCRIPT_DIR}../share/iTMSTransporter.woa/iTMSTransporter "$@"
"${SCRIPT_DIR}../share/iTMSTransporter.woa/iTMSTransporter" "$@"
```

I guess this behavior is caused by inproper `classpath` setup which I wasn't able to resolve though.

After fixing the script, I managed to upload my app through the XCode Organiser.

Comment: Thanks.  The solution worked out for me too.  I had path messed up on my computer and I am not able to fix my path. :(  I have a kinds of problems on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.

I tried many solutions listed on a lots of forums but none of them worked for me.

Here's what I did:

I found Application Loader at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS`

But before that I accidentally ran iTMSTransporter from terminal by using:
"`open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter`" 
and it updated by it self. I'm sure whether this was necessary.

Started Application Loader, logged in and selected the ipa file that I had created using Xcode. I started the upload process and it was success.

Now the app is in review. :)

I hope this helps.

**Edit**: To load Application Loader from terminal use this: "`open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/Application\ Loader`"

Comment: This fixed it for me, great answer.  Don't try reinstalling before you try this!!!